# Longest element of Weyl group of a simple Lie algebra action on Weyl chambers

Tags: lie-algebras, weyl-group

Let, $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex simple Lie algebra with Weyl group $W$,also let $\omega_0$ be the longest element of the Weyl group. We Know that Weyl group acts on the set of Weyl chambers freely and transitively and also $-\omega_0$ fixes the fundamental Weyl chamber(as a set). Now my question is, does it fixes all chambers,i.e Does the automorphism $-\omega_0$ is actually identity on the set of weyl chambers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each Weyl chamber can play the role of  the fundamental one, if you choose the right set of simple roots. Now if you made such a different choice, a priori that would seem to specify a different Weyl group element as "the longest one". But would it really?